# How can I find the dates for the same week a year ago?

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

This is an example of a week, from Sunday to Saturday:

```
11/21/2010 - 11/27/2010
```

I would like to find the dates for the same week Sunday-Saturday, only for last year.

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'date' # Included in Ruby's standard library, no gem needed
now = Date.today
before = Date.civil( now.year-1, now.month, now.day )
sunday = Date.commercial( before.year, before.cweek, 1 ) - 1 # Day 1 is Monday
this_week_last_year = sunday..(sunday+6)
```

**Edit:** Though `Date.commercial` is cool, it's not needed. Here's a Simpler way to find the Sunday starting the week:

```
require 'date'
now    = Date.today
before = Date.civil( now.year-1, now.month, now.day )
sunday = before - before.wday
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>> 1.year.ago.beginning_of_week.to_date
Mon, 30 Nov 2009
>> 1.year.ago.end_of_week.to_date
Sun, 06 Dec 2009
```

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse '1 year ago'
# => 2009-12-01 14:05:39 -0800
```

[Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) is a pretty sweet rubygem which can handle a range of things, including being adapted for your particular request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require 'active_support/all'
today = Time.now #=> 2010-12-01 14:58:36 -0700
sunday = (today - today.wday.days).beginning_of_day #=> 2010-11-28 00:00:00 -0700
saturday = sunday + 6.days #=> 2010-12-04 00:00:00 -0700
sunday.wday #=> 0
saturday.wday #=> 6

sunday - 1.year #=> 2009-11-28 00:00:00 -0700
sunday.prev_year #=> 2009-11-28 00:00:00 -0700
saturday - 1.year #=> 2009-12-04 00:00:00 -0700
saturday.prev_year #=> 2009-12-04 00:00:00 -0700
```

You could also figure out the week of the year for one of the two days, then subtract `365.days`

ActiveSupport was actually split into finer granularity with Rails 3, so you don't have to load in the entire suite if you don't want. I did it for simplicity. More info is on the [ActiveSupport Core Extensions page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html).

Or, you could get jiggy with string parsing:

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse('1 year ago last sunday') #=> 2009-11-28 12:00:00 -0700
Chronic.parse('1 year ago next saturday') #=> 2009-12-04 12:00:00 -0700
```

I like Chronic, and, for this sort of parsing I think it's a OK solution because the string is something you'd create, and not a user, so there's less chance of your code blowing up with an unparsable string. I'm not sure if there's a speed hit because of the parsing though so some benchmarks might be in order if the parsing was going to be in a loop.